# TeXLive with custom location does not find "biblatex.sty"

Tags: installing, texlive

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and installed TeXLive 2012 via download. I did not use the packages provided by Ubuntu. Since I don't have enough space I installed TeXLive to another partition. However, LaTeX won't find my `biblatex.sty` now. It is there.
If I run `texhash` it will update the ls-R files in the standard directories but not my custom directory.
How can I tell TeXLive to look in my custom directory for files?
It does find all my binaries.
I hope you can help me out!

**EDIT**
I still does not work from Texmaker but a simple bash script with the export as described below does the trick.

Comment: Can you report the output of the shell command "`echo $PATH`"? (No quotes; edit your question to add it)

Comment: It's `/media/sdc1/texlive/2012/bin/i386-linux:/media/sdc1/texlive/2012/bin/i386-linux:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/karsten/.rvm/bin:/media/sdc1/texlive/2012/bin/i386-linux:/home/karsten/.rvm/bin`

It works from shell now but not from Texmaker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i do the same thing as you (`12.04`, `tl 2012`).  i created a partition `/local/texlive/2012` and installed tex live into that.

when i need to use `tl` (when i'm working for myself, rather than as a sys-admin
for people who are using unadorned ubuntu tex), i add

```
/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux
```

at the front of my path.  my bash command is

```
export PATH=/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
```

which means that `tl2012` will be searched before any ubuntu-installed stuff.

texlive is configured so that it will see the `texmf` trees, by default, from its knowledge of where it was installed.

the arrangement should work for you, if you can arrange your tree(s) to look similar.

(i've been using this arrangement since 2009 (i.e., since i was diddling with tl2009.)

Comment: It works from shell if I set the path at the begining so:
`export PATH=/media/sdc1/texlive/2012/bin/i386-linux:$PATH`

It does not work in Texmaker yet.