# Setting up TexMaker on Ubuntu "biblatex.sty not found."

Tags: biblatex

**--UPDATE--**

I've installed biblatex via the command "sudo apt-get install biblatex".  However I now get a partially generated pdf like this:[image] 
instead of the desired output of: 
[image]

**--UPDATE--**

I've found TexMaker very easy and helpful with the pdf file it generated whenever you pressed the "Quick Build" button.

Sadly when I started writing slightly more complicated scripts ([my current Tex document](http://pastebin.com/qnbxgktk)) that required biblatex for references whenever I clicked on the "Quick Build" button I get the following error:

> ! LaTeX Error: File `biblatex.sty' not found.

Instead to build my pdf I need to type the following in the command line:

```
pdflatex test.tex
biber test
pdflatex test.tex
```

A similar question was asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83958/texlive-with-custom-location-does-not-find-biblatex-sty) but I really don't want to use a script each time I need to compile my Tex document.

My echo $PATH is "/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games" and here is the current configuration of TexMaker
[image: TexMaker commands]
[image: TexMaker Quick Build]

Comment: What's the output of `tlmgr install biblatex` (or with `sudo` if `not enough permissions`)?

Comment: [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092)

Comment: Where and how was `biblatex` installed, and what permissions does it have?

Comment: @T.Verron, that is strange but I get a "sudo: tlmgr: command not found".  Without the sudo I get "You don't have permission to change the installation in any way,
specifically, the directory /usr/local/texlive/2012/tlpkg/ is not writable."

Comment: @jon, I installed it by doing the following: wget http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz and then running the ./install-tl script as sudo.  With regards to TexLite all I did was install it via Ubuntu's "App Centre"

Comment: @cmhughes, I don't think I need a vanilla install of TeXLive, but rather a setup that runs with a specific set up. ie: so that quick build can build with "biblatex" (Unless I'm missing something else)

Comment: @JohnCrawford `biblatex` is a LaTeX package, so your editor does not need to know about it. If you use Biber rather than BibTeX as the 'back end' there is some set up, but first you want `biblatex` installed!

Comment: @JosephWright, I think it must be installed as I can compile my .tex document into a pdf.  However as mentioned above instead of just pressing the quick build I need to run the following from the command line: "pdflatex test.tex" and then "biber test" and lastly "pdflatex test.tex".  Surely that means that biblatex is then installed?

Comment: @JohnCrawford `kpsewhich biblatex.sty` at terminal will confirm its path and presence.

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like I didn't indeed have biblatex installed (don't know how it generated the pdf document via the command line though).  I have done a "sudo apt-get install biblatex" and now the document does get generated via TexMaker... but not fully.

Comment: @JohnCrawford You've now got `biblatex` installed but have not run `latex` then `biber`, then `latex` again, or have run `biber` but with settings expecting `bibtex`. Do you have a `.blg` file about? This is a log of what BibTeX does: it might be informative.

Comment: @JosephWright, I only get that .blg file if I run "pdflatex test.tex", then "biber test" via the command line.  Here is what it looks like: http://pastebin.com/ssdpdDxG Sadly nothing of interest. When I try and compile my Tex document via TexMaker I only get refs.bib, test.aux, test.bcf, test.log, test.run.xml and test.synctex.gz

Comment: @JohnCrawford OK, do you have a `.bbl` file and did you run `latex` again after running `biber`?

Comment: It really sounds to me like you have a mixed TeX setup of some sort: partly the 'vanilla' TeX Live from CTAN, and partly from Ubuntu's repositories: does TexLite (?) know of the CTAN install or is it working with whatever you've installed from the repositories?  If you installed `biblatex` from `apt`, that is probably *not* the 'right' `biblatex`: it is outdated, and installed in the wrong place with respect to the CTAN install.

Comment: @JosephWright, it works fine in the command line when running  "pdflatex test.tex", then "biber test" and then "pdflatex test.tex" again.  However I just want to use the button "Quick Build" in TexMaker, not the command line.  Sadly that .bbl file is only generated when I run the said commands in the command line... but *not* when I run the "Quick Build" button in TexMaker

Comment: @JohnCrawford Looking at the options you have, you'll need to choose either a pre-built script such as `latexmk`, a more flexible system such as `arara` or 'roll your own' if you want to have Biber run automatically by Texmaker. Perhaps [pop over to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) as this might need quite a bit of discussion.

Comment: See also [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So the solution was rather simple. Click on Options->Configure TexMaker.  From there click on the "Tex Build" button.  The go to the field "User" and enter the following: `pdflatex %.tex | biber % | pdflatex %.tex | evince %.pdf`  This will then generate your pdf document from your Tex file and show the output to you

Here is a screen shot of the change needed.

[image]

Comment: If you only want to use biber occasionally, or want to reserve your QuickBuild shortcut for something else, you can also define it as a user command by going to `User`->`User Commands`->`Edit User Commands` and assigning the same sequence to one of the five user commands. It will then be available via the respective shortcut or in the left of the two dropdown boxes in the main toolbar.

Answer (score 119):

This was clearly not the problem for OP, but since I came here via Googling, this might help future suffers of this message.

On my system (Linux Mint 17.2), my `texlive` installation didn't include `biber` and I had to run:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-bibtex-extra biber
```

after which all ran fine.

Comment: Your solution is extremely helpful!!, Thanks a lot!!

Comment: can I marry you?
This answer has helped me a LOT! thank you!

Comment: @eli44; haha, really nice!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and could solve it (Debian 10, TexMaker) by installing `texlive-bibtex-extra` and `texlive-lang-english`:

```
sudo apt install texlive-bibtex-extra
sudo apt install texlive-lang-english
```