# biblatex: How to separate authors names in reference?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, punctuation

I'm using biblatex for my references, and "main author's name" and "all authors names" should have been separated from the article's title as follows:
[image]

I've tried to add custom field `authors` in `.bib` file, as below:

```
@article{Abd_2014,
    author = {Abdullin A.A.},
    authors = {Abdullin A.A. AND Drozdov V.N. AND Plotitsyn},
    title = {Optimal Control System},
    journaltitle = {Advances in Automatic Control},
    date = {2014},
    pages = {22-26}
}
```

and then adding it to the preamble (I've read this in biblatex.pdf user manual file)

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}
    \usebibmacro{begentry}
    \printnames{author}
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{title}
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{authors} % \printnames or \printlist didn't help either
    \newunit
    \printfield{journaltitle}
    \newunit
    \printfield{year}   
    \newunit
    \printfield{pages}      
    \usebibmacro{finentry}
}
```

But all that I've got is:
[image]

I need to get rid of the appeared indentation, as well.

Here is the whole `.tex` file

```
\documentclass[twoside, final, 10pt]{extreport}

\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{mathtext}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pscyr}

\usepackage[a5paper,left=2.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[maxbibnames = 99, sorting = nyt, style = numeric-comp, backend = biber, bibencoding = utf8]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\adddot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\textit{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{C. #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{#1}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{\ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\AtBeginBibliography{
    \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
        \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{}{}\space}
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
    \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \printnames{author}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{title}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{authors}%
    \newunit
    \printfield{journaltitle}%
    \newunit
    \printfield{year}%
    \newunit
    \printfield{pages}%      
    \usebibmacro{finentry}
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{Abd_2014,
        author = {Abdullin A.A.},
        authors = {Abdullin A.A. AND Drozdov V.N. AND Plotitsyn},
        title = {Optimal Control System},
        journaltitle = {Advances in Automatic Control},
        date = {2014},
        pages = {22-26}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage[unicode, hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}  
    \printbibliography[heading = bibintoc, title = ЛИТЕРАТУРА]
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the label of each bibliography entry to be just the first author, i.e, the "main" author is always the first author, yes?.  This is a very non-standard system.  Also the // and dashes in between parts of the references will are non-standard too. This is doable in `biblatex` for sure, but it's a pretty extensive job, and your single example likely isn't enough to characterize all the requirements of this style.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, i.e. complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}` so we can reproduce the picture from your question.

Comment: Is this supposed to be Russian GOST style? There is `biblatex-gost` that implements the requirements of that style?

Comment: You are getting the extra indentation because you did not end some of your lines with `%`. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/35864). And `\printnames{authors}` won't work because the name field `authors` is not in the default data model - you would have to declare the field to Biber in a `.dbx` file. But if it's always the first author who is the 'main author' that is actually not necessary, then things can be automated.

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for your fast reply.

As @moewe noticed, this is supposed to be Russian GOST style. Actually, I did't know that there was `biblatex-gost` package, I'll google on that.

Comment: Also, I've added the whole `.tex` file. And again thanks to @moewe I got rid of the indentation.

To @AlanMunn - you understood it right! And it's always the first author who is the 'main author'.
To @moewe - If it isn't necessary to add extra field to have things automated then it will be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to implement the ГОСТ/GOST style, I suggest you use Oleg Do­manov's [`biblatex-gost`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-gost) package.

Unfortunately, my Russian is still not good enough to properly read [the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-gost/doc/biblatex-gost.pdf), but it seems you should simply use `style=numeric-gost` and the special `bbx:gostbibliography` toggle.

```
\toggletrue{bbx:gostbibliography}
```

I used the `movenames=false` option, but you might prefer to use the default `movenames=true`. (In the MWE you can see a difference for `aksin`.)

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[maxbibnames = 99, sorting = nyt, style = gost-numeric, backend = biber, movenames=false]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Abd_2014,
  author  = {Abdullin, A. A. AND Drozdov, V. N. AND Plotitsyn, A. A.},
  title = {Optimal Control System},
  journaltitle = {Advances in Automatic Control},
  date = {2014},
  pages = {22-26}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage[unicode, hidelinks]{hyperref}

\toggletrue{bbx:gostbibliography}

\begin{document}
    \cite{Abd_2014,sigfridsson,worman,aksin}  
    \printbibliography[heading = bibintoc, title = ЛИТЕРАТУРА]
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Please note how I changed your example `.bib` entry to use the correct name format.

Comment: Cannot run this MWE. It says: `LaTeX Error: File \`biblatex.sty' not found.`

Comment: @user2513149 Apparently you don't have `biblatex` installed. That is odd, most modern distributions should install it. What OS are you using and how did you install TeX (MikTeX or TeX live?)

Comment: I am running Ubuntu. Strangely, but `biber` wasn't installed. Solution here helped me: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281972/165867

Comment: @user2513149 So `biblatex` and Biber are now installed and running?

Comment: Yes. After doing these steps in Texmaker on Ubuntu https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154788/165867 it is working. Several times I had an error: `inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: not set up for use with LaTeX`. But after commenting and uncommenting the `\printbibliography` line everything works fine now. Maybe some caching problem, I don't know.

Comment: The error `Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:МЁ not set up for use with LaTeX.` was caused by the `\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}` line. Apparently, that file has some "bad" symbols.