# BibLaTeX - only first author and then all authors

Tags: biblatex

I need to produce the following BibLaTeX style:

[image: style]

Note that at the beginning we have only the **first** author (last name and then initials), then an article title, and only then a list of all authors (initials and then last name).

How do I enter the list of multiple authors in the `.bib` file properly and how to include it in the main `.tex` file?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a ГОСТ bibliography style, have a look at [`biblatex-gost`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-gost). See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/375189/35864

Comment: @moewe, actually, this is a new Ukrainian thesis bibliography style.

Comment: But you can still take `biblatex-gost` as a basis, can't you?

Comment: At the first look it seems suitable. Does anyone know the proper way to use it in this case?

Comment: Please see my answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/375189/35864. From what I can see the output `biblatex-gost` gives is exactly what you want, but it may well be that some details are different.

Comment: I suggest you take `biblatex-gost` as a basis and then ask new and separate questions about the things you need to change. Be sure to include a fully compilable, yet minimal example document (and [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)).